# WildFly embedded ActiveMQ Artemis: Difference between queue and jms-queue

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

What is the difference between `queue` and `jms-queue` declaration in the [server configuration in the activemq-messaging subsystem](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/messaging-activemq/server/index.html)?

Could the `queue` be used with a MessageDriven bean instead of a `jms-queue`?

I'm using Wildlfy 19 and Artemis 2.12.0

Comment: Hello Justin, thank you a lot for you answer, could you please explain more about "queue" use case, can it be used by jms client to send messages ? is there a way in server side to attach a listener (java class) to intercept if there are any message received from client (like MDB are bind to jms queue). Also when you said "ActiveMq supports JMS and other protocol", do you mean JMS is considered a protocol ?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a `queue` rather than a `jms-queue`?

Comment: I have an old activemq client that was able to connect to widfly 11 with activemq 5.8 on a queue called `queue://queue1` for example, when we upgraded to wildlfy 19 and we switched to using embedded artemis version 2.x, there is a prefix added to queue names "jms.queue.", that has prevented the old client from connecting to server because it throws AMQ229017: Queue xxxxx does not exist. As I couldn't find any way to disable the addition of prefixes in jms queue names, I 'm trying to find any other alternative.

Comment: Is your old ActiveMQ client using JNDI or is it using `javax.jms.Session.createQueue()`? If it's using the JNDI the migration should be relatively straight-forward. If not then you no doubt understand why not using JNDI is bad for portability.

Comment: It's using SessionUtil.GetDestination, it's a .NET client using apache NMS Active MQ 1.6.2

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports the JMS API, but it also supports industry standard protocols like AMQP, STOMP, OpenWire, & MQTT. Therefore the broker's underlying [address model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) is not JMS-specific but rather more generic & flexible in order to support numerous different use-cases.

The bare `queue` refers to the underlying "core" queue from ActiveMQ Artemis. I believe WildFly exposes this low-level component to support unforeseen use-cases. The `queue` configuration gives control over the `address` and `routing-type` which are the other two main components of the ActiveMQ Artemis address model.

The `jms-queue` refers to the traditional JMS-based resource which MDBs and other JMS-based application components will use in a Java/Jakarta EE application server. It gives you control of JNDI entries which `queue` does not. It serves as a kind of familiar "wrapper" around the core `queue`. That's why there's so much overlap with the attributes and operations between the two.

There's really no reason to use `queue` in lieu of `jms-queue` unless you absolutely must. A `jms-queue` is more straight-forward to configure and understand for almost all use-cases. The only reason to use a `queue` is if you needed to control the address and routing-type in a way that isn't allowed by `jms-queue`. This is highly unlikely for JMS applications.

It is possible, for example, to send messages to or consumer a message from a `queue`, but since `queue` lacks a way to configure JNDI bindings the JMS client would have to instantiate the queue directly using [`javax.jms.Session.createQueue(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-). However, this method is discouraged as it reduces the portability of the application.